# How to do authentication/authorization right in ASP.NET MVC 5 WITHOUT membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm not a fan of membership.

Personally, I find it too intrusive and difficult to seamlessly incorporate into most web applications I work on ... and as such, I've always implemented Forms based authentication myself.  I like to have explicit control of table names, routing, logic, etc... throughout the authentication without having to go through a bunch of hoops to do so.

Looking at MVC 5 and beyond, it seems to me that MS is really pushing folks down the membership path (perhaps I'm wrong), a path I'd like to avoid.

So, what is the best way to handle ASP.NET Identity right without having to resort to using membership?  Ideally, I'd like a future-proof solution that will work with the vNext bits coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds too broad. Nothing future-proof is possible. But it seems like Asp.Net Identity is here to stay, as it replaces `MembershipProvider` and is much better, allowing you to do as much customisation as you wish/need, or just use it with the default configuration (it is good enough).

And you wrong saying that MS pushes people down to Membership path - no longer the case. Asp.Net Identity is the default authentication method in default MVC5 template in VC2013.

`MembershipProvider` is dead. Go use Identity framework, it is much better!